# How do star card upgrades apply to different varieties of the same vehicle?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

There are star card upgrades that appear to be specific to abilities for just one or two varieties of a vehicle class. For example, the "Bomber Weapon Systems" card affects the Ion Cannon performance of the Bomber class. However, the TIE Bomber does not have the Ion Cannon ability (even though the card actually shows a TIE Bomber - see image below). Only Y-wings have this ability.

Does this card have any effect for vehicles of the same class which do not have the specific ability? If so, what does the ability do e.g. in the case of the TIE Bomber?

[image: Bomber Weapon Systems star card]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The cards will automatically update themselves to affect the ship that you're using.

Your example ("Bomber Weapon Systems") will affect "Ion Cannon Active Time" when you're using a Y-Wing (like your screenshot shows).

If you're using a TIE Bomber or a Hyena-Class Bomber, the exact same card will show that it affects "Missile Barrage Damage".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

it improves the common ability and not the actual specific weapon. The middle star card for bomber type ships will be improved rather than just the turret weapon for y-wings and the other bombers with blaster turrets.

Comment: I think you may have overlooked part of the question. The TIE Bomber does not have an Ion Cannon, so the card would seemingly do nothing. The question is "Does it really do nothing when there's no Ion Cannon?"